# Best way to check for one of two values in an array in PHP

Tags: php, array

I want to see if one of two values (a, b) are in an array.  Here's my current thought:

```
$match_array = array('a','b');
$array_under_test = array('b', 'd', 'f');

if (array_intersect($match_array, $array_under_test)) {
  // Success!
}
```

Any better implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to verify that *either* value is in the `$array_under_test`, `array_intersect` may not be the best option. It will continue to test for collisions even after it finds a match.

For two search strings you can just do:

```
if (in_array('a', $array_under_test) || in_array('b', $array_under_test)) {
  // Success!
}
```

This will stop searching if `'a'` is found in the `$array_under_test`.

For more than two values, you can use a loop:

```
foreach ($match_array as $value) {
  if (in_array($value, $array_under_test)) {
    // Success!
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to p.w.s.g's answer (which seems fine):

If you have lots of values you need to find, you can use a hash:

```
// the values go into keys of the array
$needles = array('value1' => 1, 'value2' => 1, 'value3' => 1);
$haystack = array('test', 'value1', 'etc');

// only go through the array once
$found = false;
foreach($haystack as $data) {
   if (isset($needles[$data])) {
       $found = true; break;
   }
 }
```

It's worth doing this if you search $haystack a lot of times.